# How are these two ways of typecasting in ActionScript 3 different?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In the [Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com) title ["ActionScript 3.0 in Flash CS3 Professional - Beyond the Basics"](http://www.lynda.com/home/displaycoursenotabs.aspx?lpk2=347&lpk67=true) Todd Perkins shows how one way of typecasting

```
var xml: XML;
xml = event.target.data as XML
```

doesn't work, while

```
var xml: XML;
xml = XML(event.target.data)
```

does. Shouldn't both forms act the same way? How are they different?
TIA
Steven

**edit**
declarations added to the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically they are different by `XML(event.target.data)` meaning "cast this to that type" where `event.target.data as XML` means "pretend it is XML".

The former is the same casting that you would expect in other languages like Java. It's a useful way to have code not need to have a try-catch block around a cast. Using `as` will either return the the first operand if it is the correct type or null otherwise.

You should take a look at the [as operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#as) if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

The `as` operator returns `null` if the left operand (`event.target.data`) is not an instance of the right operand (expected type = `XML`), whereas the typecast results in an exception in this case.

Comment: `xml` is declared as an XML type. Indeed, the `as` form returns `null`, but the second form returns the XML data from the URLLoader.

Comment: Where this answer says "left operand", it's referring to `event.target.data`, not to `xml`.